# Nautilus 43 not following gtk-theme

Tags: nautilus

I am using ubuntu-budgie 22.10 (fresh install) and i want to use nautilus instead of nemo-file-manager.
My problem is (as in firefox) that nautilus 43 is not following the gtk theme that i want to use (ark-darker)
Is there a way to bind nautilus to the system theme?
I tried to install nautilus 42 (ubuntu 22.04) but i couldn`t force the installation of nautilus.
Any suggestion?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can use a python script from https://github.com/odziom91/libadwaita-theme-changer to change the libadwaita theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nautilus (from which nemo is derived) uses the libadwaita library instead of the classical themes. The following works if nautilus has not been installed as snap:
Starting with GTK4 some applications like gnome-calculator or nautilus (files) try to prevent any theming by using the named library. A workaround that worked so far was to add one line into your ~/.profile:

```
export GTK_THEME=ark-arker
```

(or one whatever the name of the theme is)

You need to logout and in again to see the effect.
I've written some remarks on how to install a theme [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1424967/) and circumventing the [libadwaita](https://blogs.gnome.org/alatiera/2021/09/18/the-truth-they-are-not-telling-you-about-themes/) theme problem...

Nautilus is part of the Gnome project. Your decision to "downgrade" from nemo to nautilus incapacitates you to make your own choices...

Comment: Thank you @kanehekili.
It works!

Comment: Wow, that works! Thanks! (Manjaro 23, Gnome 4.4)

Comment: Yes it works. But it disables you to "just switch the theme". One of the reasons I've removed Gnome from my devices - the developers seem to follow the Microsoft doctrine: (I tell you what is good - you're too dumb to decide)